# Complete list of media on Windows Home Server not showing on DLNA devices

Tags: home-networking, streaming, windows-home-server, dlna, home-theater

I have Windows Home Server 2011 set up with various libraries shared for other devices. When I connect to say, the videos library via another computer, all the videos and sub-folders within that library are shown correctly. If I connect to the same library via my DLNA set-top box or smart TV (both are LG brand), only a subset of the videos are shown. This occurs whether the DLNA devices are connected via both WiFi and Ethernet connections

How can I make sure all media in the libraries are displayed when connecting from the set-top box or smart TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error, I'm pretty sure this was an issue regarding encoding of the files. Converting. MKV files to .AVI has got the missing media showing up.

Adding a codec pack to the server may also have resolved the issue, however I didn't try this since it's hard to get codecs without bloatware.